# Command Button to Input data into Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I hope you are all having a good post Holiday period. Just have a little question. I have created a user form with multiple entries for the user to input data into the sheet, however, I am having a little difficulty setting up the command button to input the data into the sheet.

the code:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
'Copy input values to sheet.
Dim rw As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
With ws
    .Cells(3Row, 3).Value = Me.txtDate.Value
    .Cells(ERow, 4).Value = Me.cboType.Value
    .Cells(FRow, 5).Value = Me.cboDesciption.Value
    .Cells(GRow, 6).Value = Me.txtIncomeAmount.Value
    .Cells(HRow, 7).Value = Me.txtExpensesAmount.Value
    .Cells(IRow, 7).Value = Me.txtComment.Value
    End With
    'Clear Input Controls.
    Me.txtDate = ""
    Me.cboType = ""
    Me.cboDesciption = ""
    Me.txtIncomeAmount = ""
    Me.txtExpensesAmount = ""
    Me.txtComment = ""
```

I pretty much have no coding knowledge, I've been learning off lots of different tutorials online so far. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. :) Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What are you trying to do here? `.Cells(3Row, 3)` - `3Row` should be a numeric value for the row, not whatever that is.

Comment: Where's the problem with your code? To specify a cell, use *Cell([Row], [Column])* syntax. Therefore *.Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.txtDate.Value*. This would put the date in column C (as indicated by its number 3) in the last row your code identifies as *lRow*.

Comment: Add *Option Explicit* at the top of your code sheet. Declare *Dim lRow As Long*. *rw* seems redundant. Observe that *lRow* is determined by the length of column 1 (=A) but the new row doesn't write to column A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lRow` as row reference of `.Cells()` parameter. Try below sub.

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
'Copy input values to sheet.
Dim rw As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
With ws
    .Cells(lRow, 3) = Me.txtDate
    .Cells(lRow, 4) = Me.cboType
    .Cells(lRow, 5) = Me.cboDesciption
    .Cells(lRow, 6) = Me.txtIncomeAmount
    .Cells(lRow, 7) = Me.txtExpensesAmount
    .Cells(lRow, 8) = Me.txtComment
End With

    'Clear Input Controls.
    Me.txtDate = ""
    Me.cboType = ""
    Me.cboDesciption = ""
    Me.txtIncomeAmount = ""
    Me.txtExpensesAmount = ""
    Me.txtComment = ""
End Sub
```

> ***#EIDT***

In case of table you need to find last empty cell of particular column. As per attachment your file you need to find last empty cell of `B Column` means `Date` column. So, use below codes to work for your sheet.

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
'Copy input values to sheet.
Dim rw As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long
Dim LO As ListObject
Dim LEO As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("2020_Data")
Set LO = ws.ListObjects("Table2")
'lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

With LO.Range.Columns(2)
    Set LEO = .Find(what:="", after:=.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
        searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext)
    If Not LEO Is Nothing Then
        lrow = LEO.Row
'        MsgBox LEO.Row 'First empty row at column B
    End If
End With

'rw = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
With ws
    .Cells(lrow, "B") = Me.txtDate
    .Cells(lrow, "E") = Me.cboType
    .Cells(lrow, "F") = Me.cboDesciption
    .Cells(lrow, "G") = Me.txtIncomeAmount
    .Cells(lrow, "H") = Me.txtExpensesAmount
    .Cells(lrow, "I") = Me.txtComment
End With

    'Clear Input Controls.
    Me.txtDate = ""
    Me.cboType = ""
    Me.cboDesciption = ""
    Me.txtIncomeAmount = ""
    Me.txtExpensesAmount = ""
    Me.txtComment = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Harun24HR, 
Thanks for your answer!! I have copied your code into the worksheet, however, for some reason, I am receiving a "Run Time Error 9, Subscript out of range" Would you have any advice on this one, please?

Comment: Sorry, This is the one 'Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")'

Comment: I just run the codes to my pc and found okay. Do you have worksheet with name `Sheet1`? Check your worksheet names in your workbook.

Comment: Ohh I see where I went wrong now ahaha..... thanks!! Although that error is gone, now the data is not being inputted into the sheet :(

Comment: @new11 can you share your sample workbook via google drive or dropbox and put link here to review. Code should work as work for me.

Comment: Sure thing :) please see the link below: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AnPmWD2-HbPF50gdxpDskONTnUPk?e=8Qmb8Q

Comment: @new11 See edited answer and let me know your feedback.

Comment: You are a genius, thank you so much!! It's all working as expected, all I have to do now is create a button and assign a Macro :) 
Thanks again!!!